# Superscript use in optimization formulations

Tags: optimization

What are common uses of superscripts in mathematical optimization formulations? None of my optimization books start at the level of "proper" variable labeling.  When I ask ChatGPT, it recommends time, stages, levels, layers, scenarios, and exponentiation.  These cases track from what I have seen in papers, but are there other cases?  I am working on a paper that has subgraphs, paths, subsets, and other non-sequential objects that are used as variable identifiers.  Should these just be subscripts?

Comment: My personal opinion is that superscripts are frequently used when there would otherwise be too many subscripts for easy reading ("too many" being a judgment call by the author or editor). I find it easier to read formulations where summations are indexed only over subscripts and not over superscripts, but again that is a personal preference.

Comment: If the model contains or can contain powers $x^y$ (many of my models do), superscripts become really confusing.